# How are Vetalas similar to Medusa?

Tags: mythical-creatures, hindu, medusa

According to Hindu Mythology, Vetalas are snake-like creatures. How are they similar to Medusa?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the source you mentioned is on a TV show called [Lost Girl](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1429449/).

The best source for finding relevant info on the Vetala is the [Kathasaritsagara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathasaritsagara) especially book 12

And especially the story [(better known as Vikram and the Vampire)](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/content/books/ebooks/vikram-and-the-vampire.pdf) of [Baital Pachisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baital_Pachisi)   or Twenty-five (tales of a) Baital (In Sanskrit, Vetala-pancha-Vinshati. "Baital" is the modern form of Vetala)[¹](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/content/books/ebooks/vikram-and-the-vampire.pdf)

> The twelfth book is important as it contains the plan and details of a collection of tales extremely popular in India, existing both in Sanskrit and in all the vernacular dialects, called the Vetala Panchavimshati: twenty-five tales of a Vetala being related by a sprite, who haunts cemeteries and animates dead bodies, to Vikramaditya, king of Ujjain, according to the usual version, to Trivikramasena, king of Pratishthan, on the Godavari, according to the Kathasaritsagara.<sub>[Kathasaritsagara Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathasaritsagara#Books_11_to_13)</sub>

Further information may be gleaned from the [The Imperial Gazetteer of India Vol.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Imperial_Gazetteer_of_India) a great historical reference book, which is available online for free and linked at the bottom of the quote.

> A collection of pretty and ingenious fairy-tales is the
>   Vetalapanchavimsati, or ' Twenty-five Tales of the Goblin,' stories
>   supposed to be told to king Vikrama of Ujjayini by a demon inhabiting
>   a corpse. They are known to English readers from Sir Richard Burton's
>   Vikram and the Vampire. Another collection of fairy-tales is the
>   Simhasana-dvatrimsika, or ' Thirtytwo Stories of the Lion-seat,'
>   supposed to be told to king Vikrama by his throne. Both these works
>   are of Buddhistic origin. To the same class belongs the Suka-saptati,
>   or ' Seventy Stories of a Parrot,' represented as narrated to a wife
>   whose husband is away on his travels. <sub>[The Imperial Gazetteer of
>   India (waybackmachine)](https://archive.org/details/imperialgazette02hunt/page/252/mode/2up)</sub>

¹ [page 5 line 7 of Vikram and the Vampire](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/content/books/ebooks/vikram-and-the-vampire.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The **Indo-Europeans** did not only share a common language, they also shared a common mythology and worldview. You will find much more similarities when comparing Hindu and i.e. Norse, Baltic, Welsh and other pre-christian European mythologies. I.e. all Indo-Europeans believe in a cycle of *life*, *death* and *rebirth* cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_mythology#Otherworld (this wikipedia article has severe quality problems, only as a side note)

With the spreading of monotheism this unifying worldview was disrupted, because of Muslim influence even the Hindu worldview is not purely Indo-European anymore, i.e. the **non-dualistic concept of universal balance and order** *Brahman* turned into the male (dualistic) deity Brahma (strong monotheistic influence).

The Indo-European names for the non-dualistic concept of universal balance and order are *Rta* (Vedic), Ve**rita**s (Roman), U**rda** (Norse).

*Linguistics* is an important tool in the attempt to reconstruct the (proto-) Indo-European mythology, however it is also often too interpretable